# datos dentro de un rango de fecha

Tags: php, pdf, sql, datepicker

Necesito generar un reporte PDF y que se muestren los item que esten entre un rango de fecha.

Este es el modal donde se encuentran los datepicker y el boton Generate Report con un `onclick="Report()"` que lleva a una function en `JavaScript`, donde abre el la nueva ventana con el `PDF`.

```
<input id="start" type="date">
<input id="end" type="date">
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta en la function en el js.

```
function Report()
{
      setTimeout(function(){ window.open("http://localhost/WareHouse/reporte.php?fecha=? and fecha2=?"+fecha1+fecha2, "_blank"); }, 1000);
}
```

Esta es al estructura del PDF el cual se genera si hago pruebas desde postman. Poniendo datos a mano.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <?php echo'<title>Inventory To Reorder</title>';?>
</head>

<body onload="window.print()">
  <?php echo '<img src="http://localhost/WareHouse/assets/img/logo.png" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height:6%; width:23%; margin-top:40px; margin-left:40px;"/>';?>
    <?php  echo '<center style="margin-top:120px; font-size:14pt;"><strong>Inventory To Reorder<strong></center>';?>
  <?php  echo '<label><center>____________________________________________________________________________</center></label><br>';?>
<?php

require_once('apis/connection.php');
    if(isset($_GET['fecha1']) && isset($_GET['fecha2']))
    {

      $fecha1 = $_GET["fecha1"];
      $fecha2 = $_GET["fecha2"];

      //Trae todos los item que esten por debajo de su minimo en stock.
      $connection = new MySqlServerConnection();
      $query = 'SELECT i.description_item,i.quantity,u.name_unit,i.reorder_Level,i.target_Stock,l.name_location,i.commentt,io.quantity_s
      FROM inventory_list AS i
      INNER JOIN unit_mesurement AS u ON id_unit = fkUnit
      INNER JOIN locatiON AS l on id_location = fkLocation
      INNER JOIN inventory_output as io on id_output = fkInventory
      WHERE '".$fecha1."' AND '".$fecha2."'';
      $result = $connection->executeQuery($query,array($fecha1,$fecha2));
      if ($result > 0) {
  ?>
  <center>
            <table class="table table-striped xd" border="1px;" id="tabla">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 3%;">Description</th>
                    <th style="width: 3%;">Quantity</th>
                    <th style="width: 3%;">Usage</th>
                    <th style="width: 3%;">Name Unit</th>
                    <th style="width: 3%;">Reorder Level</th>
                    <th style="width: 3%;">Target Stock</th>
                    <th style="width: 3%;">Area</th>
                    <th style="width: 3%;">Comment</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <?php
                $arraycount=count($result);
                $i=0;
                $total=0;
                while ($i < $arraycount)
                {
                  ?>
                            <tr>
                             <td><center><?php echo $result[$i]['description_item']; ?></td>
                             <td><p style="color:red;" ><?php echo $result[$i]['quantity']; ?></p></td>
                            <td>
                             <?php
                             $qs = $result[$i]['quantity_s'];
                             switch (true) {
                                case ($qs >= 1000 && $qs <= 2000) :
                                  echo " 1000 a 2000 SEMANAL";
                                 break;

                                 case ($qs >= 100 && $qs <= 200) :
                                  echo " 100 a 200 SEMANAL Y/O QUINCENAL";
                                 break;

                                 case ($qs >5 || $qs <6) :
                                  echo "5 a 6 CADA 2 SEMANAS";
                                 break;
                             }
                              ?>
                             </td>
                             <td><?php echo $result[$i]['name_unit']; ?></td>
                             <td><?php echo $result[$i]['reorder_Level']; ?></td>
                             <td><?php echo $result[$i]['target_Stock']; ?></td>
                             <td><?php echo $result[$i]['name_location']; ?></td>
                             <td><?php echo $result[$i]['commentt']; ?></center></td>
                            </tr>
                <?php $i++;
              }
                ?>
            </table><br><br>
  </center>
      <?php
      }
      //}
    }
  ?>
</body>
```

Mi problema es que no se como hacerle cuando se de click en el boton Generate Report, cachar los valores y asi mismo ejecutar el query para que me muestre los datos dentro de las fechas seleccionadas.

**El PDF y su estructura sirve poniendo datos directo en postman, ahora como hago lo mismo desde los date picker?**

Answer (score 0):

En tu js debes separar las variables que pasas con un `&` y concatenar su valor con el `+`. Te dejo un ejemplo de la función modificada.

```
function Report() {
    var fecha1 = document.getElementById('start').value;
    var fecha2 = document.getElementById('end').value;

    setTimeout(function(){ window.open("http://localhost/WareHouse/reporte.php?fecha1="+fecha1+"&fecha2="+fecha2, "_blank"); }, 1000);
}
```

Después en tu PHP debes formatear la fecha para dejarla en formato MySQL:

```php
if(isset($_GET['fecha1']) && isset($_GET['fecha2'])) {

    $fecha1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$_GET['fecha1'])));
    $fecha2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$_GET['fecha2'])));
    ...
```

Comment: Hice lo que me indicaste y funciona bien, la primer vez me trae los datos dentro del rango elegido en el datepicker, pero cuando lo vuelvo a intentar poniendo un rango donde solo me deria traer uno, no muestra nada, a que se debera eso?